# how to extract list of existing actions and parameters for each in C# via Dataverse APi

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dataverse

I need to get all existing dataverse Api executable actions and the required parameters for each(list below) in C#, is there Metadata query to run?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/actions?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9

Answer (score 0):

That specific Actions can be retrieved from the metadata, you need to download the url located at `https://yourinstance.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/$metadata` and after parse the XML file.